# Target one letter in a string with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have this string:
"hello" in a `<span>` tag, and I want to execute a code for each letter (example: hide, change opacity, etc..). How can I make this with JS/Jquery without having to do this:

```
<span>h</span><span>e</span><span>l</span><span>l</span><span>o</span>
```

Comment: You could try targeting with the pseudo css pseudo class `:nth-letter()` but I'm can't say for sure if jQuery does allows that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: dynamically styled hello #4]

[image: dynamically styled hello #2]

A couple examples here, to randomly apply a color and size to each character, without wrapping each letter in a `span` tag.

`forEach` loop method:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/2prwh01f/)

```js
var span = document.querySelector('span')
var str = span.innerHTML
span.innerHTML = ''
str.split('').forEach(function (elem) {
    var newSpan = document.createElement('span')
    newSpan.style.color = "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16)
    newSpan.style.fontSize = (Math.random() * (36 - 10) + 10) + 'px'
    newSpan.innerHTML = elem
    span.appendChild(newSpan)
})
```

```html
<span>hello</span>
```

---

`setTimeout` method:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/j38k5yhx/)

```js
var span = document.querySelector('span')
var str_arr = span.innerHTML.split('')
span.innerHTML = ''
var ii = 0
~function crazy(ii, str_arr, target) {
    if ( ii < str_arr.length ) {
        var newSpan = document.createElement('span')
        newSpan.style.color = "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16)
        newSpan.style.fontSize = (Math.random() * (72 - 36) + 36) + 'px'
        newSpan.innerHTML = str_arr[ii]
        target.appendChild(newSpan)
        setTimeout(function () {
            crazy(ii += 1, str_arr, target)
        }, 1000)
    }
}(ii, str_arr, span)
```

```html
<span>hello</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

In html

```
<span id="my-text">hello</span>
<div id="split-span" ></div>
```

In Javascript,

```
var text = $('#my-text').html().split('');

for(var i=0; i<text.length; i++){
    $('#split-span').append('<span>'+text[i]+'</span>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this fairly easily in vanilla javaScript without the need of a library like jquery. You could use `split` to convert your string into an array. This puts each letter into an index of the array. From here you can add markup to each index (or letter) with a loop.

example:

```
   var str = "hello";
   var res = str.split(''); 

   for( var i = 0; i < res.length; i++ ){
     res[ i ] = '<span>' + res[ i ] + '</span>'
   }
```